# Nodejs how to detect if module is included

Tags: node.js

How can I detect if server.js is included or directly ran, so I can export.server or just server.listen(port) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#accessing_the_main_module

> When a file is run directly from Node, require.main is set to its module. That means that you can determine whether a file has been run directly by testing
>
> `require.main === module`